# why drawRect method is not being called?

Tags: iphone, drawrect

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface quartzViewController : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UIView *myView;

}

@end


#import "quartzViewController.h"

@implementation quartzViewController


   -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
   {   

 CGContextRef  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 24, kCGEncodingFontSpecific);
 CGContextSetTextPosition(context,80,80);
 CGContextShowText(context, "hello", 6);
 //not even this works
 CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 1,1, "hello", 6);
   }

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [myView setNeedsDisplay];

 [super viewDidLoad];
   }
```

Will I have to make any changed in the nib?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've subclassed UIViewController which has no drawRect to override. drawRect is a method of UIView.

Comment: yeah thanx for the reply, i have got my answer, you are right, I took a new class which i inherit from UIVIEW and i found drawRect method ,which is not called...

Comment: If you got the answer then you should select them as accepted . you can read the FAQ .

Answer (score 3):

drawRect: is a `UIView` method, not a `UIViewController` method.

Answer (score 0):

i have got my answer, I took a new class which i inherit from UIVIEW and i found drawRect method ,which is not called..

THE MISTAKE WAS, i was declaring the method in UIVIEWCONTRLLER CLASSS,  rather i had to do it 
in a new class in herited from UIView.

Comment: FYI- Stack Overflow works a little different than most forums out there. the convention here is to mark the "correct" answer with a check mark rather than create a new "answer". that way future users can quickly see what worked for the original poster...and contributors get "reputation" points for helping out. And YOU should get a few points for selecting an answer and effectively "closing" this topic.